# Hallway light switch makes bedroom light brighter

Tags: lighting

When I turn my bedroom light switch on, the ceiling light turns on and seems fine. (*Older North American home.*)

When I then turn the switch for the hallway light on, the bedroom light becomes brighter.

Is the bedroom light somehow now getting 240v instead of 120v? And what would cause this?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/518202/152903

Comment: Set your  microwave to defrost, and heat a cup of water. On defrost, which will make the microwave cycle the magnetron on/off every few seconds.  While that runs watch the bedroom light. Does it change brightness as the microwave cycles?

Comment: Start by measuring the AC voltage wherever you can, perhaps at the bedroom switch itself.  And as always: is this a new phenomenon?  Did you change anything else? What do you mean by "older" house?  Some people would call a 2000 construction "older," while I would think "pre WW2"  .

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that there's a split circuit (Multi wire branch circuit) improperly wired here.

So when both switches are on, you're getting 240v between the two phases rather than the expected 120v between a single phase and neutral.

Comment: This is called a lost or floating neutral, and results in uneven division of the 240 VAC, e.g. 80 VAC on one circuit with low resistance (e.g. a refrigerator), and 160 on a ight load (e.g. a few LED and incandescent lamps). It can destroy equipment and start fires.

Comment: How would this be resolved? Or is a certified electrician the only route?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that even 160 VAC wouldn't cause incandescent bulbs to pop immediately.

Comment: With a mwbc the 2 legs are 180 out of phase With the return on the neutral there will always be 240 between the 2 legs but the max voltage to ground is 120v.